# Centering msform by css

Tags: javascript, html, css

What am I doing wrong? I want to center form (#msform, #msform fieldset) on all browsers and I want to keep image in border form, stretch form, don`t go beyond the right border...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bj8pd5op/38/)

```
#msform {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: absolute;
}
```

Please help..

Comment: **DO YO HAVE A FEVER?** - `No` - **YOU ARE HEALTHY!** ... lol, ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the width of `#msform` to `100%` or so and the same goes for the `img`

Copied your snippet here:

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;
  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  if ($(this).attr('name') == 'feveryes')
    next_fs = $('#feveryes');
  if ($(this).attr('name') == 'feverno')
    next_fs = $('#feverno');
  if ($(this).attr('name') == 'coughyes')
    next_fs = $('#coughyes');
  if ($(this).attr('name') == 'coughno')
    next_fs = $('#coughno');
  if ($(this).attr('name') == 'previous')
    next_fs = $('#firstField');

  //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

  //show the next fieldset
  next_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
      scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
      left = (now * 50) + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      //current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
      next_fs.css({
        'left': left,
        'opacity': opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".previous").click(function() {
  if (animating) return false;
  animating = true;

  current_fs = $(this).parent();
  previous_fs = $('#firstField');

  //de-activate current step on progressbar
  $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

  //show the previous fieldset
  previous_fs.show();
  //hide the current fieldset with style
  current_fs.animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
      //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
      //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
      scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
      //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
      left = ((1 - now) * 50) + "%";
      //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
      opacity = 1 - now;
      current_fs.css({
        'left': left
      });
      previous_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
        'opacity': opacity
      });
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function() {
      current_fs.hide();
      animating = false;
    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
  });
});

$(".submit").click(function() {
  return false;
});
```

```css
/*custom font*/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  /*Image only BG fallback*/
  background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
  /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.2), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.2)), url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
}

body {
  font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/*form styles*/

#msform {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#msform fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
  position: absolute;
}


/*Hide all except first fieldset*/

#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}

#msform img {
  width: 80%;
}


/*inputs*/

#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}


/*buttons*/

#msform .action-button {
  width: 100px;
  background: #27AE60;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}

#msform .action-button:hover,
#msform .action-button:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}


/*headings*/

.fs-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fs-subtitle {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/*progressbar*/

#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
  counter-reset: step;
}

#progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #333;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}


/*progressbar connectors*/

#progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50%;
  top: 9px;
  z-index: -1;
  /*put it behind the numbers*/
}

#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  /*connector not needed before the first step*/
  content: none;
}


/*marking active/completed steps green*/


/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/

#progressbar li.active:before,
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #27AE60;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<form id="msform">

  <fieldset id="firstField">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Do yo have a fever?</h2>
    <input type="button" name="feveryes" class="next action-button" value="Yes" />
    <input type="button" name="feverno" class="next action-button" value="No" />
    <br><input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Reset" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="feveryes">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Do you have a cough? Do you have a cough? Do you have a cough? Do you have a cough? Do you have a cough? Do you have a cough? Do you have a cough? Do you have a cough? </h2><br><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/63/IMG_(business).svg/1280px-IMG_(business).svg.png">
    <input type="button" name="coughyes" class="next action-button" value="Yes" />
    <input type="button" name="coughno" class="next action-button" value="No" />
    <br><input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Reset" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="coughyes">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Go to Doctor!</h2>
    <br><input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Reset" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="feverno">
    <h2 class="fs-title">You are healthy!</h2>
    <br><input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Reset" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="coughno">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Be careful!</h2>
    <br><input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Reset" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the width property, use this :

```
#msform {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Also use `max-width: 100%;` on your image in the next step.